# Error:Already finished after gradle build

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am trying to run the application from an android studio on my physical device. But every time I do that, the `Gradle Build` shows this error

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug] 
Information:BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 10s 
Error:Already finished 
Information:BUILD FAILED in 10s 
Information:1 error 
Information:0 warnings 
Information:See complete output in console
```

I went through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47600021/gradle-project-refresh-failed-already-finished) and tried every answer but the error keeps on showing. Also, I noticed that the folder of the application contains `.gradle` folder, I tried deleting it but every time I `Rebuild Project/Clean Project` the folder appears automatically.

Also, every time I create a new project, I am facing this error.

After running `./gradlew assembleDebug --info` in the terminal, the log is shown below :

```
Initialized native services in: /home/shaloin/.gradle/native
Found daemon DaemonInfo{pid=17048, address=[fc6fb39e-af80-499f-a671-d7966fec4f29 port:33345, addresses:[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, /127.0.0.1]], state=Idle, lastBusy=1519376060898, context=DefaultDaemonContext[uid=b05f2429-3b72-4dbb-9b66-3861bb909eee,javaHome=/usr/local/android-studio/jre,daemonRegistryDir=/home/shaloin/.gradle/daemon,pid=17048,idleTimeout=10800000,daemonOpts=-Xmx1536m,-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8,-Duser.country=IN,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]} however its context does not match the desired criteria.
Java home is different.
Wanted: DefaultDaemonContext[uid=null,javaHome=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle,daemonRegistryDir=/home/shaloin/.gradle/daemon,pid=553,idleTimeout=null,daemonOpts=-Xmx1536m,-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8,-Duser.country=IN,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]
Actual: DefaultDaemonContext[uid=b05f2429-3b72-4dbb-9b66-3861bb909eee,javaHome=/usr/local/android-studio/jre,daemonRegistryDir=/home/shaloin/.gradle/daemon,pid=17048,idleTimeout=10800000,daemonOpts=-Xmx1536m,-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8,-Duser.country=IN,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]

  Looking for a different daemon...
The client will now receive all logging from the daemon (pid: 335). The daemon log file: /home/shaloin/.gradle/daemon/4.1/daemon-335.out.log
Starting 2nd build in daemon [uptime: 3 mins 8.377 secs, performance: 99%, no major garbage collections]
Using 4 worker leases.
Creating new cache for fileHashes, path /home/shaloin/AndroidStudioProjects/CodeSearch/.gradle/4.1/fileHashes/fileHashes.bin, access org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess@70f708a8
Creating new cache for plugin-use-metadata, path /home/shaloin/.gradle/caches/4.1/plugin-resolution/plugin-use-metadata.bin, access org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess@79864311
Creating new cache for client-status, path /home/shaloin/.gradle/caches/4.1/plugin-resolution/client-status.bin, access org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess@79864311
Starting Build
Settings evaluated using settings file '/home/shaloin/AndroidStudioProjects/CodeSearch/settings.gradle'.
Projects loaded. Root project using build file '/home/shaloin/AndroidStudioProjects/CodeSearch/build.gradle'.
Included projects: [root project 'CodeSearch', project ':app']

> Configure project :
Evaluating root project 'CodeSearch' using build file '/home/shaloin/AndroidStudioProjects/CodeSearch/build.gradle'.
Creating new cache for metadata-1.1/results, path /home/shaloin/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/metadata-1.1/results.bin, access org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess@740f0509
Creating new cache for metadata-2.23/module-metadata, path /home/shaloin/.gradle/caches/modules-2/metadata-2.23/module-metadata.bin, access org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess@6663ad7c
Creating new cache for metadata-2.23/artifact-at-repository, path /home/shaloin/.gradle/caches/modules-2/metadata-2.23/artifact-at-repository.bin, access org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess@6663ad7c

> Configure project :app
Evaluating project ':app' using build file '/home/shaloin/AndroidStudioProjects/CodeSearch/app/build.gradle'.
Creating configuration androidTestUtil
Creating configuration compile
Creating configuration apk
Creating configuration provided
Creating configuration api
Creating configuration implementation
Creating configuration runtimeOnly
Creating configuration compileOnly
Creating configuration wearApp
Creating configuration annotationProcessor
Creating configuration androidTestCompile
Creating configuration androidTestApk
Creating configuration androidTestProvided
Creating configuration androidTestApi
Creating configuration androidTestImplementation
Creating configuration androidTestRuntimeOnly
Creating configuration androidTestCompileOnly
Creating configuration androidTestWearApp
Creating configuration androidTestAnnotationProcessor
Creating configuration testCompile
Creating configuration testApk
Creating configuration testProvided
Creating configuration testApi
Creating configuration testImplementation
Creating configuration testRuntimeOnly
Creating configuration testCompileOnly
Creating configuration testWearApp
Creating configuration testAnnotationProcessor
Creating configuration debugCompile
Creating configuration debugApk
Creating configuration debugProvided
Creating configuration debugApi
Creating configuration debugImplementation
Creating configuration debugRuntimeOnly
Creating configuration debugCompileOnly
Creating configuration debugWearApp
Creating configuration debugAnnotationProcessor
Creating configuration androidTestDebugCompile
Creating configuration androidTestDebugApk
Creating configuration androidTestDebugProvided
Creating configuration androidTestDebugApi
Creating configuration androidTestDebugImplementation
Creating configuration androidTestDebugRuntimeOnly
Creating configuration androidTestDebugCompileOnly
Creating configuration androidTestDebugWearApp
Creating configuration androidTestDebugAnnotationProcessor
Creating configuration testDebugCompile
Creating configuration testDebugApk
Creating configuration testDebugProvided
Creating configuration testDebugApi
Creating configuration testDebugImplementation
Creating configuration testDebugRuntimeOnly
Creating configuration testDebugCompileOnly
Creating configuration testDebugWearApp
Creating configuration testDebugAnnotationProcessor
Creating configuration releaseCompile
Creating configuration releaseApk
Creating configuration releaseProvided
Creating configuration releaseApi
Creating configuration releaseImplementation
Creating configuration releaseRuntimeOnly
Creating configuration releaseCompileOnly
Creating configuration releaseWearApp
Creating configuration releaseAnnotationProcessor
Creating configuration testReleaseCompile
Creating configuration testReleaseApk
Creating configuration testReleaseProvided
Creating configuration testReleaseApi
Creating configuration testReleaseImplementation
Creating configuration testReleaseRuntimeOnly
Creating configuration testReleaseCompileOnly
Creating configuration testReleaseWearApp
Creating configuration testReleaseAnnotationProcessor
Parsing the SDK, no caching allowed
SDK initialized in 17 ms
Using incremental javac compilation for :app debug.
Using incremental javac compilation for :app debugUnitTest.
Using incremental javac compilation for :app release.
Using incremental javac compilation for :app releaseUnitTest.
Using incremental javac compilation for :app debugAndroidTest.

All projects evaluated.
Selected primary task 'assembleDebug' from project :
Creating new cache for annotation-processors, path /home/shaloin/AndroidStudioProjects/CodeSearch/.gradle/4.1/fileContent/annotation-processors.bin, access org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess@72abf1bc
Tasks to be executed: [task ':app:preBuild', task ':app:preDebugBuild', task ':app:compileDebugAidl', task ':app:compileDebugRenderscript', task ':app:checkDebugManifest', task ':app:generateDebugBuildConfig', task ':app:prepareLintJar', task ':app:generateDebugResValues', task ':app:generateDebugResources', task ':app:mergeDebugResources', task ':app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests', task ':app:processDebugManifest', task ':app:splitsDiscoveryTaskDebug', task ':app:processDebugResources', task ':app:generateDebugSources', task ':app:javaPreCompileDebug', task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac', task ':app:compileDebugNdk', task ':app:compileDebugSources', task ':app:mergeDebugShaders', task ':app:compileDebugShaders', task ':app:generateDebugAssets', task ':app:mergeDebugAssets', task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug', task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug', task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug', task ':app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders', task ':app:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug', task ':app:transformNativeLibsWithStripDebugSymbolForDebug', task ':app:processDebugJavaRes', task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug', task ':app:validateSigningDebug', task ':app:packageDebug', task ':app:assembleDebug']
Creating new cache for resourceHashesCache, path /home/shaloin/AndroidStudioProjects/CodeSearch/.gradle/4.1/fileHashes/resourceHashesCache.bin, access org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess@70f708a8
Creating new cache for fileSnapshots, path /home/shaloin/AndroidStudioProjects/CodeSearch/.gradle/4.1/taskHistory/fileSnapshots.bin, access org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess@37a72cc7
Creating new cache for taskHistory, path /home/shaloin/AndroidStudioProjects/CodeSearch/.gradle/4.1/taskHistory/taskHistory.bin, access org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess@37a72cc7
:app:preBuild (Thread[Task worker for ':',5,main]) started.

> Task :app:preBuild
Skipping task ':app:preBuild' as it has no actions.

:app:preBuild (Thread[Task worker for ':',5,main]) completed. Took 0.0 secs.
:app:preDebugBuild (Thread[Task worker for ':',5,main]) started.

> Task :app:preDebugBuild
Putting task artifact state for task ':app:preDebugBuild' into context took 0.0 secs.
Creating new cache for metadata-2.23/module-artifacts, path /home/shaloin/.gradle/caches/modules-2/metadata-2.23/module-artifacts.bin, access org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess@6663ad7c
Skipping task ':app:preDebugBuild' as it is up-to-date (took 0.104 secs).

:app:preDebugBuild (Thread[Task worker for ':',5,main]) completed. Took 0.106 secs.
:app:compileDebugAidl (Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 2,5,main]) started.

> Task :app:compileDebugAidl
Putting task artifact state for task ':app:compileDebugAidl' into context took 0.0 secs.
Skipping task ':app:compileDebugAidl' as it is up-to-date (took 0.012 secs).

:app:compileDebugAidl (Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 2,5,main]) completed. Took 0.013 secs.
:app:compileDebugRenderscript (Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 2,5,main]) started.

> Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript
Putting task artifact state for task ':app:compileDebugRenderscript' into context took 0.0 secs.
Skipping task ':app:compileDebugRenderscript' as it is up-to-date (took 0.006 secs).

:app:compileDebugRenderscript (Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 2,5,main]) completed. Took 0.007 secs.
:app:checkDebugManifest (Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 3,5,main]) started.

> Task :app:checkDebugManifest
Putting task artifact state for task ':app:checkDebugManifest' into context took 0.0 secs.
Skipping task ':app:checkDebugManifest' as it is up-to-date (took 0.001 secs).

:app:checkDebugManifest (Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 3,5,main]) completed. Took 0.001 secs.
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig (Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 3,5,main]) started.

> Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig
Putting task artifact state for task ':app:generateDebugBuildConfig' into context took 0.0 secs.
Skipping task ':app:generateDebugBuildConfig' as it is up-to-date (took 0.004 secs).

:app:generateDebugBuildConfig (Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 3,5,main]) completed. Took 0.004 secs.
:app:prepareLintJar (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 2,5,main]) started.

> Task :app:prepareLintJar
Putting task artifact state for task ':app:prepareLintJar' into context took 0.0 secs.
Skipping task ':app:prepareLintJar' as it is up-to-date (took 0.005 secs).

:app:prepareLintJar (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 2,5,main]) completed. Took 0.005 secs.
:app:generateDebugResValues (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 2,5,main]) started.

> Task :app:generateDebugResValues
Putting task artifact state for task ':app:generateDebugResValues' into context took 0.0 secs.
Skipping task ':app:generateDebugResValues' as it is up-to-date (took 0.001 secs).

:app:generateDebugResValues (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 2,5,main]) completed. Took 0.002 secs.
:app:generateDebugResources (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 2,5,main]) started.

> Task :app:generateDebugResources
Skipping task ':app:generateDebugResources' as it has no actions.

:app:generateDebugResources (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 2,5,main]) completed. Took 0.001 secs.
:app:mergeDebugResources (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 2,5,main]) started.

> Task :app:mergeDebugResources
Putting task artifact state for task ':app:mergeDebugResources' into context took 0.0 secs.
Skipping task ':app:mergeDebugResources' as it is up-to-date (took 0.042 secs).

:app:mergeDebugResources (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 2,5,main]) completed. Took 0.043 secs.
:app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests (Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 2,5,main]) started.

> Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests
Putting task artifact state for task ':app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests' into context took 0.0 secs.
Skipping task ':app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests' as it is up-to-date (took 0.001 secs).

:app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests (Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 2,5,main]) completed. Took 0.002 secs.
:app:processDebugManifest (Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 2,5,main]) started.

> Task :app:processDebugManifest
Putting task artifact state for task ':app:processDebugManifest' into context took 0.0 secs.
Skipping task ':app:processDebugManifest' as it is up-to-date (took 0.005 secs).

:app:processDebugManifest (Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 2,5,main]) completed. Took 0.008 secs.
:app:splitsDiscoveryTaskDebug (Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 2,5,main]) started.

> Task :app:splitsDiscoveryTaskDebug
Putting task artifact state for task ':app:splitsDiscoveryTaskDebug' into context took 0.0 secs.
Skipping task ':app:splitsDiscoveryTaskDebug' as it is up-to-date (took 0.001 secs).

:app:splitsDiscoveryTaskDebug (Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 2,5,main]) completed. Took 0.001 secs.
:app:processDebugResources (Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 2,5,main]) started.

> Task :app:processDebugResources
Putting task artifact state for task ':app:processDebugResources' into context took 0.001 secs.
Skipping task ':app:processDebugResources' as it is up-to-date (took 0.028 secs).

:app:processDebugResources (Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 2,5,main]) completed. Took 0.029 secs.
:app:generateDebugSources (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 2,5,main]) started.

> Task :app:generateDebugSources
Skipping task ':app:generateDebugSources' as it has no actions.

:app:generateDebugSources (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 2,5,main]) completed. Took 0.0 secs.
:app:javaPreCompileDebug (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 2,5,main]) started.

> Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug
Putting task artifact state for task ':app:javaPreCompileDebug' into context took 0.0 secs.
Skipping task ':app:javaPreCompileDebug' as it is up-to-date (took 0.008 secs).

:app:javaPreCompileDebug (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 2,5,main]) completed. Took 0.009 secs.
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac (Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 3,5,main]) started.

> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
Putting task artifact state for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac' into context took 0.001 secs.
file or directory '/home/shaloin/AndroidStudioProjects/CodeSearch/app/src/debug/java', not found
Skipping task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac' as it is up-to-date (took 0.009 secs).

:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac (Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 3,5,main]) completed. Took 0.012 secs.
:app:compileDebugNdk (Thread[Task worker for ':',5,main]) started.

> Task :app:compileDebugNdk
Putting task artifact state for task ':app:compileDebugNdk' into context took 0.0 secs.
Skipping task ':app:compileDebugNdk' as it has no source files and no previous output files.

:app:compileDebugNdk (Thread[Task worker for ':',5,main]) completed. Took 0.001 secs.
:app:compileDebugSources (Thread[Task worker for ':',5,main]) started.

> Task :app:compileDebugSources
Skipping task ':app:compileDebugSources' as it has no actions.

:app:compileDebugSources (Thread[Task worker for ':',5,main]) completed. Took 0.0 secs.
:app:mergeDebugShaders (Thread[Task worker for ':',5,main]) started.

> Task :app:mergeDebugShaders
Putting task artifact state for task ':app:mergeDebugShaders' into context took 0.0 secs.
Skipping task ':app:mergeDebugShaders' as it is up-to-date (took 0.001 secs).

:app:mergeDebugShaders (Thread[Task worker for ':',5,main]) completed. Took 0.002 secs.
:app:compileDebugShaders (Thread[Task worker for ':',5,main]) started.

> Task :app:compileDebugShaders
Putting task artifact state for task ':app:compileDebugShaders' into context took 0.0 secs.
Skipping task ':app:compileDebugShaders' as it is up-to-date (took 0.001 secs).

:app:compileDebugShaders (Thread[Task worker for ':',5,main]) completed. Took 0.001 secs.
:app:generateDebugAssets (Thread[Task worker for ':',5,main]) started.

> Task :app:generateDebugAssets
Skipping task ':app:generateDebugAssets' as it has no actions.

:app:generateDebugAssets (Thread[Task worker for ':',5,main]) completed. Took 0.0 secs.
:app:mergeDebugAssets (Thread[Task worker for ':',5,main]) started.

> Task :app:mergeDebugAssets
Putting task artifact state for task ':app:mergeDebugAssets' into context took 0.0 secs.
Skipping task ':app:mergeDebugAssets' as it is up-to-date (took 0.006 secs).

:app:mergeDebugAssets (Thread[Task worker for ':',5,main]) completed. Took 0.006 secs.
:app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug (Thread[Task worker for ':',5,main]) started.

> Task :app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug
Putting task artifact state for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug' into context took 0.0 secs.
Skipping task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug' as it is up-to-date (took 0.015 secs).

:app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug (Thread[Task worker for ':',5,main]) completed. Took 0.015 secs.
:app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug (Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 3,5,main]) started.

> Task :app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug
Putting task artifact state for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug' into context took 0.0 secs.
Skipping task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug' as it is up-to-date (took 0.005 secs).

:app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug (Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 3,5,main]) completed. Took 0.006 secs.
:app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug (Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 3,5,main]) started.

> Task :app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug
Putting task artifact state for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug' into context took 0.0 secs.
Skipping task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug' as it is up-to-date (took 0.004 secs).

:app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug (Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 3,5,main]) completed. Took 0.005 secs.
:app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders (Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 3,5,main]) started.

> Task :app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders
Putting task artifact state for task ':app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders' into context took 0.0 secs.
Skipping task ':app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders' as it is up-to-date (took 0.001 secs).

:app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders (Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 3,5,main]) completed. Took 0.003 secs.
:app:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug (Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 3,5,main]) started.

> Task :app:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug
Putting task artifact state for task ':app:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug' into context took 0.0 secs.
Skipping task ':app:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug' as it is up-to-date (took 0.012 secs).

:app:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug (Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 3,5,main]) completed. Took 0.013 secs.
:app:transformNativeLibsWithStripDebugSymbolForDebug (Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 3,5,main]) started.

> Task :app:transformNativeLibsWithStripDebugSymbolForDebug
Putting task artifact state for task ':app:transformNativeLibsWithStripDebugSymbolForDebug' into context took 0.0 secs.
Skipping task ':app:transformNativeLibsWithStripDebugSymbolForDebug' as it is up-to-date (took 0.011 secs).

:app:transformNativeLibsWithStripDebugSymbolForDebug (Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 3,5,main]) completed. Took 0.012 secs.
:app:processDebugJavaRes (Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 3,5,main]) started.

> Task :app:processDebugJavaRes
Putting task artifact state for task ':app:processDebugJavaRes' into context took 0.0 secs.
Skipping task ':app:processDebugJavaRes' as it has no source files and no previous output files.

:app:processDebugJavaRes (Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 3,5,main]) completed. Took 0.002 secs.
:app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug (Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 3,5,main]) started.

> Task :app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug
Putting task artifact state for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug' into context took 0.0 secs.
Skipping task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug' as it is up-to-date (took 0.013 secs).

:app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug (Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 3,5,main]) completed. Took 0.015 secs.
:app:validateSigningDebug (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 2,5,main]) started.

> Task :app:validateSigningDebug
Putting task artifact state for task ':app:validateSigningDebug' into context took 0.0 secs.
Executing task ':app:validateSigningDebug' (up-to-date check took 0.0 secs) due to:
  Task has not declared any outputs.

:app:validateSigningDebug (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 2,5,main]) completed. Took 0.009 secs.
:app:packageDebug (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 2,5,main]) started.

> Task :app:packageDebug
Putting task artifact state for task ':app:packageDebug' into context took 0.0 secs.
Skipping task ':app:packageDebug' as it is up-to-date (took 0.023 secs).

:app:packageDebug (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 2,5,main]) completed. Took 0.027 secs.
:app:assembleDebug (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 2,5,main]) started.

> Task :app:assembleDebug
Skipping task ':app:assembleDebug' as it has no actions.

:app:assembleDebug (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 2,5,main]) completed. Took 0.001 secs.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
26 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 25 up-to-date
```

Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: can you execute `./gradlew assembleDebug --info` and post the whole log.

Comment: @Christopher, since I am new to this, could you please tell me as to where do I execute the command?

Comment: just in a shell/terminal/bash with your project root as current directory.

Comment: @Christopher, I have updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1** (This is not my answer, credit goes to this [user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37418429/8086064) and this [user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44176673/8086064))

The cause turned out to be that I had defined a new configuration in the "Run/Debug Configurations" dialog and put the full path to the build.gradle file in the Gradle project: field, as follows. (I did this by clicking the ellipsis (...) button to the right of the field, but I could also have entered it directly.)

[image]

However, what I should have done was follow the pattern in existing configurations, where the Gradle project: was specified as a "registered project", by clicking the "folder" icon to the right of the field, highlighted in green in the following image. In this case, the content of the field is just the project name, and is shown with subtly different background/foreground colours. (I accidentally discovered that right-clicking on this name will replace it with the path to the folder containing build.gradle, but if you cancel and start editing the configuration again, it will still appear as just the project name.)

[image]

After that in you `gradle.properties` insert the lines below (all credit goes to this [user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44176673/8086064)) :

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m
org.gradle.java.home=${path to java sdk}
```

You can get the path of `java sdk` by using the following 
steps ([reference](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1054731)) :

**Step 1**

```
$ whereis java
java: /usr/bin/java /etc/java /usr/share/java
```

**Step 2**

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/java
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 2009-01-15 18:34 /usr/bin/java -> 
/etc/alternatives/java
```

**Step 3**

```
$ ls -l /etc/alternatives/java
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 31 2009-01-15 18:34 /etc/alternatives/java -> 
/usr/local/jre1.6.0_07/bin/java
```

The actual location of java: /usr/local/jre.....

In my case the sdk was present in `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64`, and I just replaced the `${path to java sdk}` with `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64` and that's it, I was good to go.

**Solution 2**

The above solution worked for me, but I also tried uninstalling and then re-installing the android studio. It worked too.